# Create table-like string from list of dicts

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list, pdf

I have the following list of dicts. I would like to change its format to a string that looks like a table having fixed columns (Library, Vulnerability ID, Severity, Installed Version, Fixed Version, Title)

```
[
  {
    "Target": "docker:17.06.0-dind (alpine 3.6.2)",
    "Type": "alpine",
    "Vulnerabilities": [
      {
        "VulnerabilityID": "CVE-2017-15873",
        "PkgName": "busybox",
        "InstalledVersion": "1.26.2-r5",
        "FixedVersion": "1.26.2-r9",
        "Layer": {
          "DiffID": "sha256:5bef08742407efd622d243692b79ba0055383bbce12900324f75e56f589aedb0"
        },
        "SeveritySource": "nvd",
        "Title": "busybox: Integer overflow in the get_next_block function",
        "Description": "The get_next_block function in archival/libarchive/decompress_bunzip2.c in BusyBox 1.27.2 has an Integer Overflow that may lead to a write access violation.",
        "Severity": "MEDIUM",
        "CweIDs": [
          "CWE-190"
        ],
        "VendorVectors": {
          "nvd": {
            "v2": "AV:N/AC:M/Au:N/C:N/I:N/A:P",
            "v3": "CVSS:3.0/AV:L/AC:L/PR:N/UI:R/S:U/C:N/I:N/A:H"
          },
          "redhat": {
            "v3": "CVSS:3.0/AV:L/AC:L/PR:N/UI:R/S:U/C:N/I:N/A:L"
          }
        },
        "CVSS": {
          "nvd": {
            "V2Vector": "AV:N/AC:M/Au:N/C:N/I:N/A:P",
            "V3Vector": "CVSS:3.0/AV:L/AC:L/PR:N/UI:R/S:U/C:N/I:N/A:H",
            "V2Score": 4.3,
            "V3Score": 5.5
          },
          "redhat": {
            "V3Vector": "CVSS:3.0/AV:L/AC:L/PR:N/UI:R/S:U/C:N/I:N/A:L",
            "V3Score": 3.3
          }
        },
        "References": [
          "https://bugs.busybox.net/show_bug.cgi?id=10431",
          "https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2017-15873",
          "https://git.busybox.net/busybox/commit/?id=0402cb32df015d9372578e3db27db47b33d5c7b0",
          "https://lists.debian.org/debian-lts-announce/2018/07/msg00037.html",
          "https://usn.ubuntu.com/3935-1/",
          "https://usn.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-3935-1"
        ],
        "PublishedDate": "2017-10-24T20:29:00Z",
        "LastModifiedDate": "2019-04-03T15:29:00Z"
      },
      {
        "VulnerabilityID": "CVE-2017-16544",
        "PkgName": "busybox",
        "InstalledVersion": "1.26.2-r5",
        "FixedVersion": "1.26.2-r9",
        "Layer": {
          "DiffID": "sha256:5bef08742407efd622d243692b79ba0055383bbce12900324f75e56f589aedb0"
        },
        "SeveritySource": "nvd",
        "Title": "busybox: Insufficient sanitization of filenames when autocompleting",
        "Description": "In the add_match function in libbb/lineedit.c in BusyBox through 1.27.2, the tab autocomplete feature of the shell, used to get a list of filenames in a directory, does not sanitize filenames and results in executing any escape sequence in the terminal. This could potentially result in code execution, arbitrary file writes, or other attacks.",
        "Severity": "MEDIUM",
        "CweIDs": [
          "CWE-94"
        ],
        "VendorVectors": {
          "nvd": {
            "v2": "AV:N/AC:L/Au:S/C:P/I:P/A:P",
            "v3": "CVSS:3.0/AV:N/AC:L/PR:L/UI:N/S:U/C:H/I:H/A:H"
          },
          "redhat": {
            "v3": "CVSS:3.0/AV:L/AC:L/PR:L/UI:R/S:U/C:L/I:L/A:L"
          }
        },
        "CVSS": {
          "nvd": {
            "V2Vector": "AV:N/AC:L/Au:S/C:P/I:P/A:P",
            "V3Vector": "CVSS:3.0/AV:N/AC:L/PR:L/UI:N/S:U/C:H/I:H/A:H",
            "V2Score": 6.5,
            "V3Score": 8.8
          },
          "redhat": {
            "V3Vector": "CVSS:3.0/AV:L/AC:L/PR:L/UI:R/S:U/C:L/I:L/A:L",
            "V3Score": 4.8
          }
        },
        "References": [
          "http://packetstormsecurity.com/files/154361/Cisco-Device-Hardcoded-Credentials-GNU-glibc-BusyBox.html",
          "http://packetstormsecurity.com/files/154536/VMware-Security-Advisory-2019-0013.html",
          "http://seclists.org/fulldisclosure/2019/Jun/18",
          "http://seclists.org/fulldisclosure/2019/Sep/7",
          "http://seclists.org/fulldisclosure/2020/Aug/20",
          "http://seclists.org/fulldisclosure/2020/Mar/15",
          "http://seclists.org/fulldisclosure/2020/Sep/6",
          "http://www.vmware.com/security/advisories/VMSA-2019-0013.html",
          "https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2017-16544",
          "https://git.busybox.net/busybox/commit/?id=c3797d40a1c57352192c6106cc0f435e7d9c11e8",
          "https://lists.debian.org/debian-lts-announce/2018/07/msg00037.html",
          "https://seclists.org/bugtraq/2019/Jun/14",
          "https://seclists.org/bugtraq/2019/Sep/7",
          "https://us-cert.cisa.gov/ics/advisories/icsa-20-240-01",
          "https://usn.ubuntu.com/3935-1/",
          "https://usn.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-3935-1",
          "https://www.twistlock.com/2017/11/20/cve-2017-16544-busybox-autocompletion-vulnerability/"
        ],
        "PublishedDate": "2017-11-20T15:29:00Z",
        "LastModifiedDate": "2020-09-02T21:15:00Z"
      },
      {
        "VulnerabilityID": "CVE-2017-15650",
        "PkgName": "musl",
        "InstalledVersion": "1.1.16-r10",
        "FixedVersion": "1.1.16-r14",
        "Layer": {
          "DiffID": "sha256:5bef08742407efd622d243692b79ba0055383bbce12900324f75e56f589aedb0"
        },
        "SeveritySource": "nvd",
        "Description": "musl libc before 1.1.17 has a buffer overflow via crafted DNS replies because dns_parse_callback in network/lookup_name.c does not restrict the number of addresses, and thus an attacker can provide an unexpected number by sending A records in a reply to an AAAA query.",
        "Severity": "MEDIUM",
        "CweIDs": [
          "CWE-119"
        ],
        "VendorVectors": {
          "nvd": {
            "v2": "AV:N/AC:L/Au:N/C:N/I:N/A:P",
            "v3": "CVSS:3.0/AV:N/AC:L/PR:N/UI:N/S:U/C:N/I:N/A:H"
          }
        },
        "CVSS": {
          "nvd": {
            "V2Vector": "AV:N/AC:L/Au:N/C:N/I:N/A:P",
            "V3Vector": "CVSS:3.0/AV:N/AC:L/PR:N/UI:N/S:U/C:N/I:N/A:H",
            "V2Score": 5,
            "V3Score": 7.5
          }
        },
        "References": [
          "http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/commit/?id=45ca5d3fcb6f874bf5ba55d0e9651cef68515395",
          "http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/WHATSNEW",
          "http://openwall.com/lists/oss-security/2017/10/19/5",
          "https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2017-15650",
          "https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/patch/?id=45ca5d3fcb6f874bf5ba55d0e9651cef68515395"
        ],
        "PublishedDate": "2017-10-19T23:29:00Z",
        "LastModifiedDate": "2017-11-08T16:21:00Z"
      },
      {
        "VulnerabilityID": "CVE-2017-15650",
        "PkgName": "musl-utils",
        "InstalledVersion": "1.1.16-r10",
        "FixedVersion": "1.1.16-r14",
        "Layer": {
          "DiffID": "sha256:5bef08742407efd622d243692b79ba0055383bbce12900324f75e56f589aedb0"
        },
        "SeveritySource": "nvd",
        "Description": "musl libc before 1.1.17 has a buffer overflow via crafted DNS replies because dns_parse_callback in network/lookup_name.c does not restrict the number of addresses, and thus an attacker can provide an unexpected number by sending A records in a reply to an AAAA query.",
        "Severity": "MEDIUM",
        "CweIDs": [
          "CWE-119"
        ],
        "VendorVectors": {
          "nvd": {
            "v2": "AV:N/AC:L/Au:N/C:N/I:N/A:P",
            "v3": "CVSS:3.0/AV:N/AC:L/PR:N/UI:N/S:U/C:N/I:N/A:H"
          }
        },
        "CVSS": {
          "nvd": {
            "V2Vector": "AV:N/AC:L/Au:N/C:N/I:N/A:P",
            "V3Vector": "CVSS:3.0/AV:N/AC:L/PR:N/UI:N/S:U/C:N/I:N/A:H",
            "V2Score": 5,
            "V3Score": 7.5
          }
        },
        "References": [
          "http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/commit/?id=45ca5d3fcb6f874bf5ba55d0e9651cef68515395",
          "http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/WHATSNEW",
          "http://openwall.com/lists/oss-security/2017/10/19/5",
          "https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2017-15650",
          "https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/patch/?id=45ca5d3fcb6f874bf5ba55d0e9651cef68515395"
        ],
        "PublishedDate": "2017-10-19T23:29:00Z",
        "LastModifiedDate": "2017-11-08T16:21:00Z"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I would like to change its format to the following so that I can generate a PDF with a proper format:

```
+------------+------------------+----------+-------------------+---------------+--------------------------------+
|  LIBRARY   | VULNERABILITY ID | SEVERITY | INSTALLED VERSION | FIXED VERSION |             TITLE              |
+------------+------------------+----------+-------------------+---------------+--------------------------------+
| busybox    | CVE-2017-15873   | MEDIUM   | 1.26.2-r5         | 1.26.2-r9     | busybox: Integer overflow in   |
|            |                  |          |                   |               | the get_next_block function    |
+            +------------------+          +                   +               +--------------------------------+
|            | CVE-2017-16544   |          |                   |               | busybox: Insufficient          |
|            |                  |          |                   |               | sanitization of filenames when |
|            |                  |          |                   |               | autocompleting                 |
+------------+------------------+          +-------------------+---------------+--------------------------------+
| musl       | CVE-2017-15650   |          | 1.1.16-r10        | 1.1.16-r14    | musl libc before 1.1.17 has    |
|            |                  |          |                   |               | a buffer overflow via crafted  |
|            |                  |          |                   |               | DNS replies...                 |
+------------+                  +          +                   +               +                                +
| musl-utils |                  |          |                   |               |                                |
|            |                  |          |                   |               |                                |
|            |                  |          |                   |               |                                |
+------------+------------------+----------+-------------------+---------------+--------------------------------+
```

How can I do this?

**EDIT**

I've written this code to format the list.

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable
pretty_table = PrettyTable()
big_list = [
  {
    "Target": "docker:17.06.0-dind (alpine 3.6.2)",
    "Type": "alpine",
    "Vulnerabilities": [
      {
        "VulnerabilityID": "CVE-2017-15873",
        "PkgName": "busybox",
        "InstalledVersion": "1.26.2-r5",
        "FixedVersion": "1.26.2-r9",
        "Layer": {
          "DiffID": "sha256:5bef08742407efd622d243692b79ba0055383bbce12900324f75e56f589aedb0"
        },
        "SeveritySource": "nvd",
        "Title": "busybox: Integer overflow in the get_next_block function",
        "Description": "The get_next_block function in archival/libarchive/decompress_bunzip2.c in BusyBox 1.27.2 has an Integer Overflow that may lead to a write access violation.",
        "Severity": "MEDIUM",
        "CweIDs": [
          "CWE-190"
        ],
        "VendorVectors": {
          "nvd": {
            "v2": "AV:N/AC:M/Au:N/C:N/I:N/A:P",
            "v3": "CVSS:3.0/AV:L/AC:L/PR:N/UI:R/S:U/C:N/I:N/A:H"
          },
          "redhat": {
            "v3": "CVSS:3.0/AV:L/AC:L/PR:N/UI:R/S:U/C:N/I:N/A:L"
          }
        },
        "CVSS": {
          "nvd": {
            "V2Vector": "AV:N/AC:M/Au:N/C:N/I:N/A:P",
            "V3Vector": "CVSS:3.0/AV:L/AC:L/PR:N/UI:R/S:U/C:N/I:N/A:H",
            "V2Score": 4.3,
            "V3Score": 5.5
          },
          "redhat": {
            "V3Vector": "CVSS:3.0/AV:L/AC:L/PR:N/UI:R/S:U/C:N/I:N/A:L",
            "V3Score": 3.3
          }
        },
        "References": [
          "https://bugs.busybox.net/show_bug.cgi?id=10431",
          "https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2017-15873",
          "https://git.busybox.net/busybox/commit/?id=0402cb32df015d9372578e3db27db47b33d5c7b0",
          "https://lists.debian.org/debian-lts-announce/2018/07/msg00037.html",
          "https://usn.ubuntu.com/3935-1/",
          "https://usn.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-3935-1"
        ],
        "PublishedDate": "2017-10-24T20:29:00Z",
        "LastModifiedDate": "2019-04-03T15:29:00Z"
      },
      {
        "VulnerabilityID": "CVE-2017-16544",
        "PkgName": "busybox",
        "InstalledVersion": "1.26.2-r5",
        "FixedVersion": "1.26.2-r9",
        "Layer": {
          "DiffID": "sha256:5bef08742407efd622d243692b79ba0055383bbce12900324f75e56f589aedb0"
        },
        "SeveritySource": "nvd",
        "Title": "busybox: Insufficient sanitization of filenames when autocompleting",
        "Description": "In the add_match function in libbb/lineedit.c in BusyBox through 1.27.2, the tab autocomplete feature of the shell, used to get a list of filenames in a directory, does not sanitize filenames and results in executing any escape sequence in the terminal. This could potentially result in code execution, arbitrary file writes, or other attacks.",
        "Severity": "MEDIUM",
        "CweIDs": [
          "CWE-94"
        ],
        "VendorVectors": {
          "nvd": {
            "v2": "AV:N/AC:L/Au:S/C:P/I:P/A:P",
            "v3": "CVSS:3.0/AV:N/AC:L/PR:L/UI:N/S:U/C:H/I:H/A:H"
          },
          "redhat": {
            "v3": "CVSS:3.0/AV:L/AC:L/PR:L/UI:R/S:U/C:L/I:L/A:L"
          }
        },
        "CVSS": {
          "nvd": {
            "V2Vector": "AV:N/AC:L/Au:S/C:P/I:P/A:P",
            "V3Vector": "CVSS:3.0/AV:N/AC:L/PR:L/UI:N/S:U/C:H/I:H/A:H",
            "V2Score": 6.5,
            "V3Score": 8.8
          },
          "redhat": {
            "V3Vector": "CVSS:3.0/AV:L/AC:L/PR:L/UI:R/S:U/C:L/I:L/A:L",
            "V3Score": 4.8
          }
        },
        "References": [
          "http://packetstormsecurity.com/files/154361/Cisco-Device-Hardcoded-Credentials-GNU-glibc-BusyBox.html",
          "http://packetstormsecurity.com/files/154536/VMware-Security-Advisory-2019-0013.html",
          "http://seclists.org/fulldisclosure/2019/Jun/18",
          "http://seclists.org/fulldisclosure/2019/Sep/7",
          "http://seclists.org/fulldisclosure/2020/Aug/20",
          "http://seclists.org/fulldisclosure/2020/Mar/15",
          "http://seclists.org/fulldisclosure/2020/Sep/6",
          "http://www.vmware.com/security/advisories/VMSA-2019-0013.html",
          "https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2017-16544",
          "https://git.busybox.net/busybox/commit/?id=c3797d40a1c57352192c6106cc0f435e7d9c11e8",
          "https://lists.debian.org/debian-lts-announce/2018/07/msg00037.html",
          "https://seclists.org/bugtraq/2019/Jun/14",
          "https://seclists.org/bugtraq/2019/Sep/7",
          "https://us-cert.cisa.gov/ics/advisories/icsa-20-240-01",
          "https://usn.ubuntu.com/3935-1/",
          "https://usn.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-3935-1",
          "https://www.twistlock.com/2017/11/20/cve-2017-16544-busybox-autocompletion-vulnerability/"
        ],
        "PublishedDate": "2017-11-20T15:29:00Z",
        "LastModifiedDate": "2020-09-02T21:15:00Z"
      },
      {
        "VulnerabilityID": "CVE-2017-15650",
        "PkgName": "musl",
        "InstalledVersion": "1.1.16-r10",
        "FixedVersion": "1.1.16-r14",
        "Layer": {
          "DiffID": "sha256:5bef08742407efd622d243692b79ba0055383bbce12900324f75e56f589aedb0"
        },
        "SeveritySource": "nvd",
        "Description": "musl libc before 1.1.17 has a buffer overflow via crafted DNS replies because dns_parse_callback in network/lookup_name.c does not restrict the number of addresses, and thus an attacker can provide an unexpected number by sending A records in a reply to an AAAA query.",
        "Severity": "MEDIUM",
        "CweIDs": [
          "CWE-119"
        ],
        "VendorVectors": {
          "nvd": {
            "v2": "AV:N/AC:L/Au:N/C:N/I:N/A:P",
            "v3": "CVSS:3.0/AV:N/AC:L/PR:N/UI:N/S:U/C:N/I:N/A:H"
          }
        },
        "CVSS": {
          "nvd": {
            "V2Vector": "AV:N/AC:L/Au:N/C:N/I:N/A:P",
            "V3Vector": "CVSS:3.0/AV:N/AC:L/PR:N/UI:N/S:U/C:N/I:N/A:H",
            "V2Score": 5,
            "V3Score": 7.5
          }
        },
        "References": [
          "http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/commit/?id=45ca5d3fcb6f874bf5ba55d0e9651cef68515395",
          "http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/WHATSNEW",
          "http://openwall.com/lists/oss-security/2017/10/19/5",
          "https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2017-15650",
          "https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/patch/?id=45ca5d3fcb6f874bf5ba55d0e9651cef68515395"
        ],
        "PublishedDate": "2017-10-19T23:29:00Z",
        "LastModifiedDate": "2017-11-08T16:21:00Z"
      },
      {
        "VulnerabilityID": "CVE-2017-15650",
        "PkgName": "musl-utils",
        "InstalledVersion": "1.1.16-r10",
        "FixedVersion": "1.1.16-r14",
        "Layer": {
          "DiffID": "sha256:5bef08742407efd622d243692b79ba0055383bbce12900324f75e56f589aedb0"
        },
        "SeveritySource": "nvd",
        "Description": "musl libc before 1.1.17 has a buffer overflow via crafted DNS replies because dns_parse_callback in network/lookup_name.c does not restrict the number of addresses, and thus an attacker can provide an unexpected number by sending A records in a reply to an AAAA query.",
        "Severity": "MEDIUM",
        "CweIDs": [
          "CWE-119"
        ],
        "VendorVectors": {
          "nvd": {
            "v2": "AV:N/AC:L/Au:N/C:N/I:N/A:P",
            "v3": "CVSS:3.0/AV:N/AC:L/PR:N/UI:N/S:U/C:N/I:N/A:H"
          }
        },
        "CVSS": {
          "nvd": {
            "V2Vector": "AV:N/AC:L/Au:N/C:N/I:N/A:P",
            "V3Vector": "CVSS:3.0/AV:N/AC:L/PR:N/UI:N/S:U/C:N/I:N/A:H",
            "V2Score": 5,
            "V3Score": 7.5
          }
        },
        "References": [
          "http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/commit/?id=45ca5d3fcb6f874bf5ba55d0e9651cef68515395",
          "http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/WHATSNEW",
          "http://openwall.com/lists/oss-security/2017/10/19/5",
          "https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2017-15650",
          "https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/patch/?id=45ca5d3fcb6f874bf5ba55d0e9651cef68515395"
        ],
        "PublishedDate": "2017-10-19T23:29:00Z",
        "LastModifiedDate": "2017-11-08T16:21:00Z"
      }
    ]
  }
]


pretty_table.field_names = ["Library", "Vulnerability ID", "Severity", "Installed version", "Fixed Version", "Title"]
pretty_table.align['Title'] = 'l'
pretty_table._max_width = {"Title": 50}

for row in big_list:
  if row['Vulnerabilities'] != 'null':
    for vuln in row['Vulnerabilities']:
      pretty_table.add_row([vuln['PkgName'],vuln['VulnerabilityID'], vuln['Severity'], vuln['InstalledVersion'],
      vuln['FixedVersion'], vuln['Description']
      ])

print(pretty_table)
```

But my problem, is that I can't write it as it is to a PDF file.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Did you have a look at: https://pypi.org/project/texttable ?

Comment: I've edited my question